# How to update GIgabyte X58 BIOS in 64bit Windows?

Tags: 64-bit, bios, updates

I want to update my EX58 GIGABYTE motherboard but there is no 64-bit BIOS update tool available. I'm getting this:

```
--------------------------- Unsupported 16-Bit Application
--------------------------- The program or feature
"\??\X:\Downloads\motherboard_bios_ga-ex58-ud4_f7d\FLASHSPI.EXE"
cannot start or run due to
incompatibility with 64-bit versions of
Windows. Please contact the software
vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows
compatible version is available.


--------------------------- OK   
---------------------------
```

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried a DOS boot disk? I think FLASHSPI can run from DOS.

Comment: Warning: Because BIOS flashing is potentially risky, if you do not encounter problems using the current version of BIOS, it is recommended that you not flash the BIOS. If you want to flash the BIOS, do it with caution. Inadequate BIOS flashing may result in system malfunction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GIGABYTE has a tool called @BIOS which will check their main server for the most recent version of firmware for your motherboard, download, and flash the BIOS.

Here is a link: http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Support/Motherboard/Utility_DownloadFile.aspx?FileType=Utility&FileID=150

Comment: The URL in your post is a broken link; here's a working one: http://www.gigabyte.com/MicroSite/121/tech_a_bios.htm

Comment: Be careful when relying on @BIOS to update your MB firmware, it doesn't always get the latest version available from the GIGABYTE support site.

Comment: The servers are down but you can download from your countries website and flash from file as well!

Answer (score 3):

If there is a Floppy based version of the BIOS update, use that (if you have to, you may need to buy a USB based floppy drive or barrow a friend's).

Other ideas include creating a BartPE/UltimateBoot CD for Windows (UBCD4WIN)/Windows PE CD and trying to install from that.

Is there a specific reason you are updating the BIOS?  When it comes to BIOS, I GENERALLY follow the thinking that "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" - if you need some new functionality of the new BIOS, that's one thing, but if you're upgrading just because there's an upgrade, at least with BIOS, I don't consider that wise.

Reference Links:

- Ultimate Boot CD for Windows (requires XP or 2003) - http://www.ubcd4win.com
- Windows Automated Installation Kit (WAIK - Windows PE is a part of this; doesn't require XP or 2003 but can be comparatively difficult to create a CD) - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C7D4BC6D-15F3-4284-9123-679830D629F2

EDIT: Also remembered - there are boot CDs you can make - DOS boot CDs that can skip the floppy - I've only done it once and it worked ok.  Check out www.bootdisk.com (but just remember, you need a DOS version of the BIOS updater for that to work)

And just to clarify - 64 bit versions of Windows have ZERO support for 16 bit applications, so that 16 bit app will never run.  If there's a 32 bit version, that MIGHT work, but apps that interact directly with hardware like that often NEED to be 64 bit on a 64 bit system. (Although I suppose if a 16 bit BIOS update app works on a 32 bit system, then a 32 bit BIOS update app might just work fine on a 64 bit system)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the suggestions found a better solution called Qflash - http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/FileList/NewTech/old_motherboard_newtech/tech_qflash.htm . A feature of GIGABYTE motherboards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it from FreeDOS?  http://www.freedos.org/

Answer (score 0):

The above link is outdated. Here is the updated link

https://www.gigabyte.com/MicroSite/121/tech_a_bios.htm

Comment: First of all, Welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please do not post comments as an answer.  Please see the following Stack Exchange guidance regarding this scenario:  [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)  Thanks for your help!